# React Native | MobX vs route.params Performance

Tags: react-native, routes, navigation, mobx

In a react native project using MobX, it would be more efficient to save the data for use on the next page. Or is it sending as params with the route? Suppose we are sending 50 pieces of data in Data.

```
//the page I will use the data

//option1
const {data} = route.params;

//option2
const {data} = Store;
```

Which one is better to use in terms of performance? Does the data I send with the route affect the rendering time of the opened page?